# SAS error using %cif macro

Tags: macros, sas

I am trying to run a `%cif` macro but I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: (execution) Invalid argument to function.

count     : number of occurrences is 2
operation : EXP at line 1436 column 1
operands  : _TEM1008
_TEM1008   7851 rows      1 col    (numeric)

statement : ASSIGN at line 1436 column 1
```

I have only been using `SAS` for a few months, so would be grateful is someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that causes the problem, including the full source code of all macros used. Without this information it is highly unlikely that anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: What version of SAS are you running?